# Query echo duplicated values when selecting two tables

Tags: php, pdo

I have a site that prints out all the registered users .
the query worked fine until i wanted to add value from another table.
now its printing out duplicated values.

lets say I have 2 users . it supposed to print out

John Doe
Jane Doe

But after adding the table with the avatar it prints out
John Doe
Jane Doe
John Doe
Jane Doe

This is my query.

```
<?php 
function fetch_users(){
global $db;
$query = $db->query("SELECT user.id, user.username,user.email, userdetails.profile_img FROM user , userdetails");
$user = array();
while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !==FALSE) { 
 $user[] = $row;
}
return $user;
}
?>
```

But If i remove the last added table userdetails and use the query without adding the table to the name. it work fine again, but then witout the avatar ofscourse.

php.

```
<?php foreach(fetch_users() as $user){  ?>
 <p>
 <a href="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $user['id'];?>"><?php echo $user['username'];?> </a>
 </p>
 <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: you're seeing a cartesian product of the tables because you're joining the tables without a condition. Try specifying `WHERE` caluse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [MySQL joins.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

For instance, you could do something like the following:

```
SELECT user.id, user.username, user.email, userdetails.profile_img
FROM user
LEFT JOIN userdetails
ON user.id = userdetails.<user id column name goes here>
GROUP BY user.id
```

This assumes you have (which you should definitely have, if you don't) a column in the userdetails table which contains keys to reference the user table by id.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm, was unsure if i really needed the left join, but now I see why.
Thank you master @Leng

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user.id, user.username,user.email, userdetails.profile_img FROM user , userdetails
```

This query selects once per user and the whole userdetails table (John Doe + John Doe | John Doe + Jane Doe | Jane Doe + John Doe | Jane Doe + Jane Doe = 4 rows)

You have to write there also a condition:

```
SELECT user.id, user.username,user.email, userdetails.profile_img FROM user , userdetails WHERE user.id = userdetails.id
```

(supposing that you have in both tables the user ID)